# Bootstrap 3 Carousel images have padding until they become active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

As you can see for yourself in the below url, the incoming image on the carousel has some padding or white background around, and as soon as item becomes active, it kindof zooms in and fits perfectly.
http://altana.al/webdev/exterior.html

Let me know any opinions, cannot seem to find anything.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with padding so in main.css line 714 add `padding:0;`

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    padding: 0;
  }
```